# Is there a way to optimize this custom made function?

Tags: php, optimization

I made this function and because I use it on the entire site I want to know if it is a way to optimize it, to make it run faster? I would also want to know if I thinked well the function? Thanks.

```
// function to get the seo friendly url of a video based on it's id 
function video_seo_urls($video_id)
{ 
    global $site_url;
    $sql = dbquery('SELECT `post_name`, `new_post_name`, `category` FROM `videos` WHERE `id` ="'.$video_id.'" LIMIT 0,1;'); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $post_name = $row["post_name"];
        $new_post_name = $row["new_post_name"];
        $category_id = $row["category"];
    }

    $csql = dbquery('SELECT `category_slug` FROM `categories` WHERE `category_id` = "'.$category_id.'" LIMIT 0,1;');
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($csql))
    {
        $category = $row["category_slug"];
    }

    if ($new_post_name !== "")
    {
        $video_slug = $new_post_name;
    } 
    else if ($new_post_name == "" && $post_name !== "")
    {
         $video_slug = $post_name;
    }

    $video_url = $site_url.'video/'.$category.'/'.$video_slug.'/'; 
    return $video_url;

} 

echo video_seo_urls(14775);
```

Comment: Is it really so slow that you have to optimize?

Comment: Holy cow -- do you really write unformatted code like this? Please format and comment it if you expect people to help you improve it.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was posted via mobile

Comment: "It works, but how can I make it better?" questions should go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: +1 for "custom made function"

Comment: I didn't know about that section. Is anybody here who can move this post there?

Comment: @mvds I didn't get that. It was a joke right? Well, I can say i am a novice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two queries could be merged into one by using a JOIN.  The syntax would look something like:

```
$sql = dbquery('SELECT v.`post_name`, v.`new_post_name`, v.`category` FROM `videos` AS v JOIN 'category_slug' AS cs ON cs.category=v.category WHERE v.`id` ="'. mysql_real_escape_string($video_id));
```

Unrelated to the speed issues, you also have a massive security hole because you are concat'ing string data into a SQL query.  If somebody was able to call this function with a video_id of "; DROP TABLE videos" you would lose your whole table.  And much worse things can happen, this is referred to as [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and you need to read up about it as it's the most common way how sites are hacked.  I used a function that will protect you from being hacked, but this is still not the best way to fix this problem, it's only considered a bandaid.

Comment: +1 for mentioning SQL injection.

Comment: Using mysql_real_escape_string before the query could save me of sql injections?

Comment: @m3tsys: Yes. (...stupid 15 char comment length minimum...)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the obvious optimization would be to merge your two SQL queries into one:

```sql
SELECT post_name, new_post_name, category, category_slug
FROM videos
  LEFT JOIN categories ON (category_id = category)
WHERE id = ?
LIMIT 1
```

(I used a left join so that the query will still give results even if there's no category with a matching ID — in that case, `category_slug` will just be NULL.)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the join allready pointed out, you really never should use mysql_fetch_array, as it consumes twice the memory (every post is returned both with a numerical key and an associative key).

Stick with

```
mysql_fetch_assoc
```

or

```
mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)
```

since you only use the result in an associative manner.

Comment: Also a good tip, I knew that one but it didn't cross my mind when I answered.  It's actually a fact many PHP devs don't realize.